# getBoundingClientRect is not a function,is undefined in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I used expo,in web style,the flowing code works fine,I can get the exactly height,width,x,y....
However,when I use in ios simulator,totally not works...
After a worling,I find that in web,`ref={addToRefs}` return a DOM,but in simulator return a `ImageBackground`...
How can I get the exactly height,width,x,y in simulator mode...

```
       <ImageBackground
        style={styles.postHeader}
        source={{ uri: `${item.posterUrl}` }}
        ref={addToRefs}
      />
```

```
  const addToRefs = (el) => {
    if (el && !refHeader.current.includes(el)) {
      refHeader.current.push(el);
    }
  };
```

```
 refHeader.current[index].getBoundingClientRect()
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm having the same problem